# How to find $E(X_1X_2X_3)$ given the joint CDF?

Tags: probability, expectation, bivariate-distributions

> Let $X_1 , X_2, X_3$ have the joint cumulative distribution function:
>
> $$
> F(X_1 , X_2 , X_3 ) = \left \{ \begin{array}{11}
> 0 \qquad X_1 < 4 \space \text{or} \space X_2 < 5 \space \text{or} \space X_3 < 6 \\
> 1 \qquad X_1 \geq 4 \space \text{and} \space X_2 \geq 5 \space \text{and} \space X_3 \geq 6.
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> Find $E[X_1 X_2 X_3]$.

The examples that I have been studying consist of instances only going from a joint PDF to a expected value, so here I am unsure. I believe that I must use the marginals of each of the variables to find the expected value, but do not know how this might be done.

Answer (score 1):

Since the joint cumulative distribution jumps from 0 to 1, this means that only values occur with the specific limitations: $X_1 = 4, X_2 = 5, X_3 = 6$. As such, we have:

$$E[X_1X_2X_3] = 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 = 120$$